# How can i fix Electron start

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, npm-install

How can i fix it?

```
Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: electron-v6.0-win32-x64-unknown
Found: [node-v57-win32-x64-unknown, node-v72-win32-x64-unknown]
This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
Original error: Cannot find module 'C:\Home\work\kvzrm\terminal\app\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\electron-v6.0-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node'
Require stack:
- C:\Home\work\kvzrm\terminal\app\node_modules\grpc\src\grpc_extension.js
```

`npm rebuild` istn work

When im use `npm i` i got

```
npm WARN node-fetch@2.6.9 requires a peer of encoding@^0.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Comment: Try running `npm i encoding` then restarting electron.

Comment: @code nothing happend

Comment: Did you try running `npm rebuild`? Are you on windows?

Comment: @code yes ive use `npm rebuild`, yes im on windows 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with the `grpc` library. First, the `grpc` library is deprecated, with `@grpc/grpc-js` as the recommended replacement. You will not have this problem with `@grpc/grpc-js`.

If you do need to use `grpc` for some reason, you need to take extra steps for it to work with Electron. These steps are detailed in the "About Electron" section of the [`grpc` README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grpc). In particular, the command you should run to get the appropriate precompiled binary for your platform is

```
npm rebuild --target=6.0.0 --runtime=electron --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron
```